# Share variable using the library reshape2

Tags: r, reshape2

I uploaded document(.csv) to the project. There is 9 column(9 variable). In the task said that it is necessary to divide a variable(wages) into groups(the average salary, median, Kurtosis,Standard deviation) but still need to indicate the gender(variable gender) and the man is married or not(variable - marital status). For example there is data:

```
wages   gender  status  ............
5000      M       NO
3000      M       Yes
4500      W       NO
2000      M       NO
3500      W       Yes
6500      M       NO
8000      W       NO
.
.
.
.
```

and if we divide on the average wages than must be:
1)for man with status NO (5000+2000+6500)/3=4500

```
wages   gender  status
4500      M       NO
```

With what methods can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for the average wage for each unique combination of gender and status? If so you could use the `dplyr` package. If, for example, your uploaded data was `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(e1071)

df <- data.frame(wages=c(5000, 3000, 4500, 2000, 3500, 6500, 8000),
                 gender=c('M', 'M', 'W', 'M', 'W', 'M', 'W'),
                 status=c('NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO'))

df_out <- df %>%
  group_by(gender, status) %>%
  summarise(avg_wage = mean(wages),
      median_val = median(wages),
      st_dev= sd(wages),
      kurt = kurtosis(wages))

df_out

# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   gender [?]
  gender status avg_wage median_val   st_dev      kurt
  <fctr> <fctr>    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1      M     NO     4500       5000 2291.288 -2.333333
2      M    YES     3000       3000       NA       NaN
3      W     NO     6250       6250 2474.874 -2.750000
4      W    YES     3500       3500       NA       NaN
```

Comment: thank. and what about median, Kurtosis,Standard deviation. can you help?

Comment: you would embed all grouped summary statistics in the `summarise` function. See updated answer. FYI you'll need to install a package for the kurtosis measurement, for me it was `e1071`.

Comment: if either answer provided helped you solve your problem, please upvote and accept that answer.